# Peer to Peer Lending Small notes Vs Large Notes

Tags: investing, peer-to-peer-lending, lending-club

I have recently started investing in lending club. Very minimum with $25 in each note. 
I was wondering which is better funding. The small notes vs large notes; 36 vs 60 terms in addition to considering the loan grades, purpose of the loans, delinquency, credit utilization   etc.

Answer (score 3):

I started with lending club about a year ago.  I love it.  It has been insightful.  Off topic, but I am in a loan to a guy who make 120K a year and is regularly late and has a pretty high interest rate.  Crazy.

You gain some economies of scale by going with a bigger note.  I have $100 notes that I get hit for 2 or 3 cents for a fee, where $25 notes are always a penny.  However, I don't think that should be your deciding factor.

I scale my note purchases based on how much I like the status of the borrower.  For example, I did $100 (which is currently my max) for a guy with a reasonable loan amount 16K, a stable work history (15+ years), a great credit history, and a great interest rate (16.9%).  If one of those things were a bit out of "whack".  I might go $50, two $25.

I prefer 36 month notes, really 5 years to get out of debt?  It is unlikely to happen IMHO.

Keep in mind that if you invest $100 in a loan, then you get one $100 note.  You can't break them up into 4 $25 notes.  For that reason, if you are likely to want to sell the note prematurely, keep it at $25.  The market is greater.

I've had a lot of success using the trading account, buying further discounted notes for people who want out of lending club, or get spooked by a couple of late payments and a change in billing date.

Another advantage of using the trading account is you start earning interest day 1.  I've had new notes take a couple of weeks to go through.

To summarize:

- I strongly prefer 36 month notes
- My minimum interest rate is 11%
- I scale between 25 and 100 based on borrower suitability
- Borrowing too much money worries me.
- If a person's occupation is NA, then auto-reject.
- Not borrowing enough to cover a revolving credit balance; or, borrowing much more worries me.
- Not having verified income worries me.

There are some other things, but that is the main stuff I look at.

Comment: Nowadays, income is rarely verified right off the bat, although if buying traded notes, one can usually examine the loan application and make a purchase decision based on that.